# Datagram socket android

Tags: android, sockets

Hi guys i'm trying to make an app that connect to my arduino device using a datagramsocket. When i launch the app it should write in my edittext ip address of  my arduino but it doesn't appear. I think the problem is that the UdcClientServer class is launched only one time at startup but it should be executed in realtime.

Here the main activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private EditText textIpScheda=null;
    private EditText textUdpPort=null;
    private UdpClientServer cu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textIpScheda = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textIpScheda);
        textUdpPort = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textUdpPort);

        try {
            cu = new UdpClientServer(this);
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public EditText getTextIpScheda(){
        return textIpScheda;
    }

    public EditText getTextUdpPort() {
        return textUdpPort;
    }
}
```

Here the UdpClientServer class:

```
    public class UdpClientServer {

    public static String sReceive;
    private static DatagramSocket dSocket;
    private Socket socket;
    private String stringa;
    int receiveBufferSize = 1024;
    int portUdp = 0;
    final String PINGACMD = "AT*PINGA001";
    InetAddress ipScheda;

    byte[] receiveData = new byte[receiveBufferSize];
    private MainActivity gui;

    public UdpClientServer(MainActivity gui) throws SocketException, IOException {
        this.gui = gui;

        portUdp = 5200;
        dSocket = new DatagramSocket(portUdp);
    }

    public void run(){
        while (true) {

            Arrays.fill(receiveData, (byte) 0);
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

            try {
                dSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ipScheda = receivePacket.getAddress();
            int port = receivePacket.getPort();
            gui.getTextUdpPort().setText("" + port);
            gui.getTextIpScheda().setText(ipScheda.getHostAddress());

            sReceive = new String(receivePacket.getData());
            this.sendCommand(PINGACMD);
        }

    }

    public void sendCommand(String outSentence){

        byte[] sendData = outSentence.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ipScheda, portUdp);

        try {
            dSocket.send(sendPacket);
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
        }
    }
}
```

thanks everybody

Comment: Are your devices on the same wifi? You may have to periodically generate some traffic on the phone to keep its wifi receptive to incomming packets.  Also, you can't update the UI from a background thread - you may have a related exception being silently caught somewhere.

Comment: yes my devices are connected to same wifi..if i run my pc application it works perfectly but on android device doesn't connect to arduino